# editing a column so that each row gets a different number

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk

I want to add an underscore and a number to each row:

input file:

```
N1
N1
N1
N1
N2
N2
N2
N2
```

output

```
N1_1
N1_2
N1_3
N1_4
N2_5
N2_6
N2_7
N2_8
```

Comment: I have multiple columns, how do i specify which one if I want the first one? I tried this code on a dummie file with 2 columns and it made the change to the second column and turned it into the first column

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adding to each row in column 1 to the number of the row](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/341894/adding-to-each-row-in-column-1-to-the-number-of-the-row)

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '{print $0 "_" NR}' input
```

This seems to do the trick.  It simply outputs the original data with an underscore and the number of lines printed so far (inclusive of the line in question) appended to the end.

To accommodate the below comment, you avail yourself of `awk`'s ability to adjust things on the fly:

```
awk '{$1 = $1 _ NR; print}' input
```

Comment: Hey thanks! I have multiple columns and the one I want to to add the _# to is the first one. How do I specify this?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how that can be done.